# CakePHP - Multiple row edits

Tags: cakephp

How can I do edits to a table on multiple rows?
I followed the tutorial here http://matsimitsu.com/blog/2008/01/06/saveall-with-cakephp.html but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I'm doing, but it's not working.

Thanks,
Tee

```
function editAll() {
    $this->data = $this->Settings->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
}
```

Then in the view, this is what I have

```
foreach ($this->data as $setting):
    echo $form->input('Setting.' . $setting['Setting']["id"] . '.value', array('value' => $setting['Setting']["value"]));
endforeach;
```

Then in the add function I have

```
function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Setting->create();
        if ($this->Setting->saveAll($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Setting has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Setting could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `id` field, so the data in your controller will look like this:

```
'Setting' => array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 42,
        'value' => 'foo'
    ),
    1 => array(…)
)
```

So in the view, do this:

```
foreach ($this->data as $i => $setting) {
    echo $this->Form->hidden("Setting.$i.id", array('value' => $setting['Setting']['id']));
    echo $this->Form->input("Setting.$i.value", array('value' => $setting['Setting']['value']));
}
```