# How to edit multiple rows of the same model at a time in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, save, edit

I'm having trouble editing multiple rows the same time in CakePHP. Let me explain:

I have a HABTM table which is:

```
GamePool (
    id -> Primary,
    pool_id -> Foreign Key to table Pools
    game_id -> Foreign Key to table Games
    guess -> just a VarChar
)
```

I was having trouble with the HABTM relation so I did the model and controller for GamePool.
What I'm trying to achieve is edit all the records on GamePool which are from a Pool. For example I have this data:

```
id    pool_id    game_id    guess
----- ---------- ---------- -----
61    23         1          L
62    23         2          E
63    23         3          V
```

After putting them in a view and editing it with a form, I end up with this data:

```
[GamePool] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 61
        [guess] => V
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 62
        [guess] => V
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 63
        [guess] => E
    )
)
```

I have this code on the edit function of the GamePools controller:

```
public function edit() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->GamePool->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Pool Saved!");
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash("Couldn't save pool, please try again");
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I try to save it says that the pool couldn't be saved.
I also tried setting on a hidden input the pool_id and game_id value because I thought it could be a validation error, but the same result... Please help!! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is multiple rows ? or multiple table rows in database ?

Comment: What do you mean? They are multiple table rows in the database...

Comment: Do you have two table with relation ? do you want to edit two table at a time ?

Comment: No, I just want to edit the multiple records on just one table

Comment: see this ans  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657164/cakephp-multiple-row-edits?rq=1

Comment: ALready did, and tried, the only difference I have is I don't call create() method because I'm editing, not adding...